# Vs code pre debugging flutter

Tags: flutter, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a flutter project. I debug it in Visual Studio Code and write the code. Before Visual Studio Code can debug, it needs to decode string text to `base64` and create a file. Then I want to debug the project. Is this possible in vs code?

Comment: Can you add some code or explain what you have tried so far?

Comment: You can create a file using base64. I want to convert json provided by google services to base64 and create while debugging. Debug after base64 conversion

Comment: It is still not clear. It could help to provide some example.

Comment: A little too vague, but I hope this is helpful: VS Code has this `launch.json` file inside the `.vscode` directory where you can store all the launch configurations. Each of these configurations can optionally have the `preLaunchTask` property specified. The tasks can be defined in the `tasks.json` file. You can define such a task that does the conversion and set it as a `preLaunchTask` for your debug launch config.

Comment: how can i debug the script in the image   https://prnt.sc/c9xIfg9lN7Er

Comment: how do i write the script in the image in debug json.